# Статус 500, при PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, router, put

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой. Т.к mongoose не имеет метода patch, решил попробовать сделать самостоятельно.

Когда я формирую объект foundUser, с помощью underscore _().pick(), с последующим добавление поля с хэшэм пароля в ответе получаю 500, хоть убей.

Когда же формирую при помощи добавления каждого параметра (Закомментированный код), у меня все хорошо апдейтится.

Суть в том, что я не хочу изменять конкретное поле и апдейтить юзера в зависимости от пришедших параметров, я хочу обновлять его целиком, полностью перезаписывая все поля.

В чем может быть причина такой реакции на pick или я что-то неправильно делаю?

```
// Patch
users.put('/:_id',
    (req, res, next) => {
        let _id = req.params._id;
        let params = req.body;

        User.findOne({_id: _id})
            .then(foundUser => {

                foundUser = _(params).pick('nickName', 'email', 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName');

                if (_(params).has('password'))
                    foundUser.password = passHelpers.makePassword(params.password);

                // if (_(params).has('nickName'))
                //  foundUser.nickName = params.nickName;

                // if (_(params).has('email'))
                //  foundUser.email = params.email;

                // if (_(params).has('password'))
                //  foundUser.password = passHelpers.makePassword(params.password);

                // if (_(params).has('firstName'))
                //  foundUser.firstName = params.firstName;

                // if (_(params).has('middleName'))
                //  foundUser.middleName = params.middleName;

                // if (_(params).has('lastname'))
                //  foundUser.lastName = params.lastName;

                // if (_(params).has('phone'))
                //  foundUser.phone = params.phone;

                console.log(foundUser); // equal params obj.
                console.log(typeof foundUser); // object

                foundUser.save()
                    .then(updatedUser => {
                        res.status(200).send();
                        res.json(updatedUser);
                        next();
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            });
    }
);
```